# Cancelled alarm is shown to be up

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have read questions on stackoverflow on how to check if an alarm exists for a pending intent.

I check if my alarm exists this way:

```
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, 
    new Intent("com.my.package.MY_UNIQUE_ACTION"), 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

I set an alarm and check is it exist and then cancel the alarm. The alarm is actually cancelled but if run the above statement again, it still returns true.

I have registered the broadcast receiver statically in manifest.

My methods to set and cancel alarms are like this:

```
    public static void cancelRecurringAlarm(Context context, String intentAction) {
    Logger.mlog(DEBUG_TAG, "cancelRecurringAlarm called with intent " + intentAction);
    Intent reminder = new Intent();
    reminder.setClass(context, <receiverClassName>);
    reminder.setAction(intentAction);
    PendingIntent recurringReminder = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, reminder, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.cancel(recurringReminder);
}

public static void setRecurringAlarm(String intentAction, Context context, long timeInMs) {
    Logger.mlog(DEBUG_TAG, "setRecurringAlarm called with intent " + intentAction);

    Intent reminder = new Intent();
    reminder.setClass(context,  <receiverClassName>);
    reminder.setAction(intentAction);
    PendingIntent recurringReminder = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, reminder, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, timeInMs, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, recurringReminder);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the Boolean value always as **true** because **you are cancelling the alarm not the pending intent**.So  cancel your pending intent recurringReminder.cancel() in cancelRecurringAlarm(). Then you will get the Boolean value as **false** after cancelling alarm

Comment: You are right. `cancel()` on pending intent somehow missed me.